# Access denied in MediaWiki database, which even affects SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I have been working on a separate database for my second MediaWiki wiki (converter.penguinicewikis.com/mw19/) for a wiki family, but there are some problems with it. However, I get error 1142 on that wiki, which says that the SELECT command is denied for the database user to the user table. Also, I tried granting privileges to my second database, and MySQL gave me Error #1044, which said that access was denied for an unknown user to the database of my first wiki. [Here is a screenshot of error 1044.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwWzs.png) Now below is the database error.

[W8j4VnacQMZDrez3KCaLSwAAABE] /mw19/ Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1149 of /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading?
Query: SELECT user_id,user_name,user_real_name,user_email,user_touched,user_token,user_email_authenticated,user_email_token,user_email_token_expires,user_registration,user_editcount FROM `gjlxrtap_mw19758`.`mwd50q_user` WHERE user_id = '1' LIMIT 1
Function: User::loadFromDatabase
Error: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'gjlxrtap_mw34555'@'localhost' for table 'mwd50q_user' (localhost)
Backtrace:

## 0 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(979): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)

## 1 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1343): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string)

## 2 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1411): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->select(string, array, array, string, array, array)

## 3 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(1287): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->selectRow(string, array, array, string, array)

## 4 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(496): User->loadFromDatabase(integer)

## 5 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(892): User->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)

## 6 [internal function]: WANObjectCache->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)

## 7 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(1012): call_user_func_array(Closure, array)

## 8 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(898): WANObjectCache->doGetWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array, NULL)

## 9 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(521): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array)

## 10 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(441): User->loadFromCache()

## 11 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(405): User->loadFromId(integer)

## 12 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/UserInfo.php(88): User->load()

## 13 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/CookieSessionProvider.php(119): MediaWiki\Session\UserInfo::newFromId(string)

## 14 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(487): MediaWiki\Session\CookieSessionProvider->provideSessionInfo(WebRequest)

## 15 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(190): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionInfoForRequest(WebRequest)

## 16 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/WebRequest.php(735): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionForRequest(WebRequest)

## 17 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(129): WebRequest->getSession()

## 18 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/Setup.php(762): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::getGlobalSession()

## 19 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/WebStart.php(114): require_once(string)

## 20 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/index.php(40): require(string)

## 21 {main}

Comment: I'm sorry, but my web host provider only appears to s jowSQL queries in PhpMyAdmin, and not MySQL commands. My web host provider is Webhostface. Also, when I type that command into SQL queries, it gives me the following error: #1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'cpses_gjswe1acl9'@'localhost' for table 'gjlxrtap_mw19758'. I wonder if there is an easy way to fix error 1142.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows that MediaWiki uses the MySQL username "gjlxrtap_mw34555" which don't have privileges on your database gjlxrtap_mw19758.

You run this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON gjlxrtap_mw19758 TO gjlxrtap_mw34555 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

in MYSQL should give the according rights and clear the privvileges cache.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my web host provider only appears to allow SQL queries in PhpMyAdmin, and not MySQL commands. My web host provider is Webhostface. Also, when I type that command into SQL queries, it gives me the following error: #1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'cpses_gjswe1acl9'@'localhost' for table 'gjlxrtap_mw19758'. I wonder if there is an easy way to fix error 1142